# Digital automatic gain control?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, gain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating dBFs from RSSI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45569/calculating-dbfs-from-rssi)

My RF chip doesn't have any RSSI output, just ADC I and Q. I was wondering is it possible to determine RSSI from ADC's I and Q values and adjust gain regarding to this? Someone suggested calculating RSSI as a vector magnitude.

$$
RSSI = \sqrt{I^2 + Q^2}
$$

Or could I just look at the outputs from ADC and if they aren't using full digital range e.g. 12bits, after some sample period, I make my AGC decision based on this.

Any good papers available about doing digital automatic gain control based only about ADC's I and Q outputs? Because all the papers those I have found from the net, usually use RSSI value for AGC.

Comment: See [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/45570/11683) to a related question; I think it covers your question as well.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you for your answer. I was just wondering because he says:
"Normally, you would want to adjust your gain to stay within the maximimum vector rotatable to any phase, ie, I or Q = 2047 and the other zero, or their sum of squares = 2047, so that is what should be considered full scale."
Shouldn't it be I or Q = 2047 and the other zero, or their sum of squares = 2047², not 2047?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.